# Complete removal of the status bar in Flutter and full screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I remove the status bar with the following code, but it doesn't fill the whole screen and a black bar comes instead

```
     SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.leanBack);
```

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

Comment: Did you tried using `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.fullScreen)` ? also make sure the asset used matches the device height.

Comment: try to remove safeArea

Comment: I did not use the safearea

Comment: The code `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUI Mode(SystemUiMode.fullScreen)`  is not correct

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, it's the notch that is causing it, which is the camera in this case, you can fix this by going to:

> android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

And adding the following line:
`<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>`

This is what my "styles.xml" now looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item> <!-- This is the added line -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Make sure to do the same for the other "styles.xml" file if you have it in "values-nigh" folder. I did run "flutter clean" before it worked.

Comment: I tried it skeptically but it really worked...wow!. Would you mind explaining what `<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>` actually means?